# Wait for a select_list to exist and then select a value

Tags: page-object-gem

I am trying to select an option from a select list using page-object. I am using IE8(have to) which is very slow when interacting with page-object.

```
When /^the user selects the Test Region "([^"]*)"$/ do |regionname| 
 on_page(MyTestRegion) do |page|
  page.region  = /#{regionname}/    if regionname != "" && regionname != {}
 end
end
```

I get Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element error.

I need to wait for the select_list element to load and then select a value.

I did try visible?, wait_until, wait_when_present, when_present but nothing so far seem to work... Is there an alternate way to wait until a element is loaded?

Comment: Given that you have mentioned most of the wait methods, are you sure you are locating the element correctly (ie did you verify that if you manually load the page and wait for the list to load that your page object can interact with the list? In other words, are you sure it is a wait problem? Waits are only required due to things being loaded asynchronously, not beacause the browser is slow.

Comment: Yes. The object is located correctly. The script does work sometimes but sometimes it does not. It works correctly with chrome.

Comment: Have you tried using the waits with a timeout longer than the default 5 seconds? For example, `page.region_element.when_present(120).select(/#{regionname}/`

Comment: Yes I have tried. It is highly inconsistent.